# Fix invalid XML with ampersands in Python

Tags: python, xml, regex, dom, sax

I am using Python to manipulate an XML file I receive from another system. That system produces invalid XML. Mainly, it doesn't escape some of the & in the XML.

So, for example, I have some lines like that:

```
<IceCream>Ben&Jerry</IceCream>
```

Of course, when parsed with SAX or DOM it throws invalid token error.

For some more general background - it's a very large file (2MB), fairly flat, and contains a lot of data in CDATA.

What I've tried:

1. Writing a **Regex** to replace only unesacped &, without reesacaping &gt; and such: `&(?!\w{2,4};)` . It fixed it, but it escaped ampersands in CDATA, which then caused errors in a destination system. I can't unescape everything that's in CDATA afterwards because some of it needs to stay escaped.
2. Using **Beautiful (Stone) Soup**. Also unlucky. Instead of escaping loose ampersands, it created an entity (i.e. `&Jerry;`). Not Good.

Next Step will be to write my own parser using a state machine. Save me from going down that road.

It is not a complex structure (very flat, 4 layers deep at most) so perhaps regex might be able to catch areas that aren't in a CDATA.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Python bindings for [tidylib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytidylib):

```
>>> import tidylib
>>> print tidylib.tidy_document("<IceCream>Ben&Jerry</IceCream>", {"input_xml": True})[0]
<IceCream>Ben&amp;Jerry</IceCream>
```

See the official tidy documentation for a list of [parser options](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html).